# When to use the move_groupinterface and GetMotionPlan service

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am aware of the implementation of motion planning in moveit using the `move_group_interface`

If I have a simple pose goal, I can use the `moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface` to do the planning.

However, I can do the same using the `GetMotionPlan` service from `moveit_msgs`.

My question is, when should I use what? What could be the advantages and disadvantages of each method?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257261/when-to-use-the-move_groupinterface-and-getmotionplan-service/) by [R.Mehra](https://answers.ros.org/users/26660/r.mehra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2017-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `MoveGroupInterface` class is a convenience wrapper for a lot of the ROS interfaces exposed by the `move_group` node, including `GetMotionPlan`.
It builds and calls these services for you, so that you don't have to fill in all the parameters yourself.
If you feel more comfortable using the bare service, you can use them too.
Considering readability of the resulting source code `MoveGroupInterface` is usually better in my experience.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0